# To be a bit angular in one's views

Tags: idioms

What does it mean for one to be a bit angular in one's views ?

This was said while describing an author of a book. The statement was in praise of the author, and in the end adds this qualification using the conjunction: 'but'.

Comment: Not "mainstream", but a bit off to the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This term is used to mean that they hold generally quite **controversial** views. Occasionally but not often this can mean they hold **stronger** views than most.

Comment: This does fit the context.

Comment: @physkets, apologies for the comment I posted earlier - I misread your comment. I have now deleted the previous comment

Comment: Don't worry. I did not see your previous comment. It is as good as not said.